# asp.net validation when field is not required

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I need to set validation on a textbox where the user types in their email address... This is not a required field though so I want to allow the form to be submitted if the textbox contains the default text ("Email address").

I've posted the code i have already to ensure a valid email address is typed.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="errorpopup" Display="Dynamic" ID="regexpEmail"
    ValidationGroup="mySubmit" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<strong>Please enter a valid email address.</strong>"
    ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
    SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

Comment: And your question/problem is?

Comment: I need to amend the validator to allow the form to be submitted if the value in the text box is blank or "Email address".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enclose the entire regex in `(?:...)?` to make it optional.

But you're not using a very good e-mail validation regex. Aside from the fact that e-mail addresses can never reliably be validated by regular expressions, you could do a little better by using

```
^(?:[\w.%+-]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}\s*|Email address)?$
```

This will still not catch all valid addresses, and will match some invalid addresses. But short of the RFC 2822 implementation regex which spans about four or five lines of code, this is probably a good compromise.